# How to use "%" character in sql query on linux shell?

Tags: sql, linux, shell, osquery, pssh

I am trying to pull all the jdk packages installed on set of hosts by sending a sql select statement to  osquery on linux shell via pssh .

Here is the query:

`pssh -h myhosts -i 'echo "SELECT name FROM rpm_packages where name like '%jdk%';"| osqueryi --json'`

but usage of "%" is giving me below error.

`Error: near line 1: near "%": syntax error`

I tried to escape % ,but the error remains same. Any ideas how to overcome this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't getting this error from your shell but from the query parser, and it's not actually caused by the `%` character, but to the `'` that immediately precedes it.  Look at where you have quotes:

```
'echo "SELECT name FROM rpm_packages where name like '%jdk%';"| osqueryi --json'
^----------------------------------------------------^     ^-------------------^
```

These quotes are consumed by the shell when it parses the argument.  Single quotes tell the shell to ignore any otherwise-special characters inside and treat what is *within* the quotes as part of the argument -- but *not the quotes themselves.*

After shell parsing finishes, the actual, verbatim argument that gets sent to `pssh` looks like this:

```
echo "SELECT name FROM rpm_packages where name like %jdk%;"| osqueryi --json
```

Note that all of the single quotes have been erased.  The result is that your query tool sees the `%` (presumably modulus) operator in a place that it doesn't expect -- right after another operator (`like`) which makes about as much sense to the parser as `name like * jdk`.  The parser doesn't understand what it means to have two consecutive binary operators, so it complains about the second one: `%`.

In order to get a literal `'` there, you need to jump through this hoop:

```
'\''
^^^^- start quoting again
|||
|\+-- literal '
|
\---- stop quoting
```

So, to fix this, replace all `'` instances inside the string with `'\''`:

```
pssh -h myhosts -i 'echo "SELECT name FROM rpm_packages where name like '\''%jdk%'\'';"| osqueryi --json'
```

Answer (score 0):

osqueryi accepts a single statement on the command line. Eliminating the echo can make quoting a bit simpler:

```
osqueryi --json "SELECT * FROM users where username like '%jdk%'"
```

You will, however, need the quotes to pass through your `pssh` command line.

While `osqueryi` is great for short simple things, if you're building a frequent polling service, `osqueryd` with scheduled queries is generally simpler.