# Use of like "%" character in sql query changes my query when executed as shell script

Tags: sql, shell, sql-like, oracle21c

I am new to shell scripting and trying to read a list of employee IDs from a text file as part of my first shell script program and pass it to another shell script as it's an argument.
In the second script, I am using that argument on a SQL select command with a like operator. But my issue is that the command gets executed as something else.

Contents of first.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
while IFS= read -r line; 
do
/d/ShellScripts/second.sh  $line
done < "$1"
```

Contents of second.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
EMP_ID=$1
sqlplus -s user/password@//localhost:1521/xepdb1 <<EOF
alter session set current_schema = HR;
set linesize 1000
select * from employees where EMPLOYEE_ID like "\'"%$EMP_ID"\'" ;
select * from employees where EMPLOYEE_ID like %{$EMP_ID} ;
EOF
```

Contents of list.txt

```
101
102
103
```

Command executed in the shell

```
$ ./first.sh list.txt

Session altered.

"\'"ct * from employees where EMPLOYEE_ID like "\'"%101
                                                   *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00911: invalid character

}elect * from employees where EMPLOYEE_ID like %{101
                                               *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00911: invalid character
```

I tried to take help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61831974/how-to-use-character-in-sql-query-on-linux-shell).
I am just trying to execute a normal SQL query using like operator, using shell scripts.

Comment: (a) in general you should quote your variable uses. eg. `"$line"`; (b) `list.txt` probably contains embedded `\r` (DOS-style line endings) that you need to strip; (c) `"\'"%$EMP_ID"\'"` and `%${EMP_ID}` should both probably just be `"%$EMP_ID"`

Comment: Hello jhnc, I tried your suggested method and found the following issue `Session altered.

"elect * from employees where EMPLOYEE_ID like "%101
                                               *
ERROR at line 1:
": invalid identifier
`

Comment: that's because you haven't stripped the `\r` from your input file (and also apparently because oracle wants `''%EMP_ID'` rather than `"%EMP_ID"` for string literals)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to escape the character's single quotation mark (') in the bash script. Simply surrounding the variable in a single quotation mark is enough.

You can change your second.sh script lines from this

```
select * from employees where EMPLOYEE_ID like "\'"%$EMP_ID"\'" ;
select * from employees where EMPLOYEE_ID like %{$EMP_ID} ;
```

to

```
select * from employees where EMPLOYEE_ID like '%$EMP_ID' ;
```

Comment: I tried a different approach where I try to match strings
so I ran the below 2 queries simultaneously in the same manner

list.txt
`David`

second.sh
`select first_name||' '||last_name "Name" from employees where first_name='David';
select first_name||' '||last_name "Name" from employees where first_name='{EMP_ID}';`

output
`Session altered.


Name
----------------------------------------------
David Austin
David Bernstein
David Lee


no rows selected`
I am very new to this, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @DipayanRay Try the queries for concatenating two columns as shown : ->

select concat( first_name, '  ', last_name ) as "Name" from employees where first_name='David';


I noticed that you are passing the wrong variable (EMP_ID) to column 'first_name', change your second query column "first_name" to  "EMPLOYEE_ID" and fix the  '{EMP_ID}' variable with '$EMP_ID' as shown ->


select concat( first_name, '  ', last_name ) as "Name" from employees where EMPLOYEE_ID = '$EMP_ID';

Comment: I fixed the variable name, below 3 lines are being executed with EMP_F_Name passed as an argument to second.sh
`select first_name,last_name from employees where first_name='David';
select first_name,last_name from employees where first_name='$EMP_F_Name';
select first_name,last_name from employees where first_name=$EMP_F_Name;`

Now, for 1st line I get 3 rows as output, 2nd line I get `no rows selected`, 3rd line I get `ORA-00904: "DAVID": invalid identifier`
What should I do to get the value properly placed in the query?